# PHP get public facing base directory from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I would like to be able to tell what the base directory of a site is automatically. Say I have a website in this location on a Unix machine:

```
/home/webserver/mywebsite
```

And it's publicly accessible here:

```
http://mywebsite.devserver.com/temp
```

I would like to be able to move the website from "temp" to the root of the site without having to manually change my php configuration files in my framework.

I guess what I need is the public facing directory of the index.php file, so say I have a .htaccess rewrite rule that means:

```
http://mywebsite.devserver.com/pages/page
```

.. will load the index.php file in the root and will return the page at /pages/page, I would need the "base directory" of the site to return "" (An empty string) because the site belongs directly after the domain name. But then say I put the site inside a directory like:

```
http://mywebsite.devserver.com/directory/pages/page
```

I would need the "base directory" to return "directory" so I can use it within the code elsewhere.

I am very sorry if this sounds vague and I will happily explain more if needed but any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I understand that what you need is a way of routing the request from your URL to different folders in your application, is that right?

Comment: I'm very sorry for my ignorance but I'm a little confused as to what you mean. In laymen's terms I need to return a string that contains the directory that the site is sitting in, but not the unix directory, the public facing directory after the domain name. I probably over cooked my original question..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]
```

It compares `REQUEST_URI` variable (which is the complete URL) with the URI matched by `RewriteRule` (which is relative to current path) and gets differential in `%{ENV:BASE}` variable.